# jasmine test for function that sets x, y click coordinates to textboxes

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, jasmine

Dev Environment: Ruby on rails, jasmine.

Function that needs testing: get click coordinates and set text field values with x, y.

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function() {
    $('.floor_map_edit').click(function(e) {
        var posX = $(this).offset().left, posY = $(this).offset().top;
        document.getElementById("location_x").value = (e.pageX - posX);
        document.getElementById("location_y").value = (e.pageY - posY);
    });
});
```

Test function in jasmine:(Tried to add fixtures, I don't know what I'm doing)

```
describe("Edit Locations", function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
            var posX,posY = null;
        loadFixtures('floor_map_click.html');
        nameFields = $(".name-field");
        spyOn($('.floor_map_edit'), "click");
        });

    it("should asset x, y coordinate inside text fields", function() {
        //$('.floor_map_edit').click();
        $('.floor_map_edit').trigger('click');
        expect($(document.getElementById("location_x")).value).toBeGreaterThan(0);
        expect($(document.getElementById("location_x")).value).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    });

});
```

Fixture:

```
<div class="floor_map_edit"><p>Hello World</p></div>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="location_x" data-id-field="id-field1" class="name-field">
    <input type="text" id="location_y" data-id-field="id-field2" class="name-field">
</form>
```

PS: I'm totally new to RoR and jasmine. I've gone through the documents to figure this much out. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need a little test helper that clicks inside an element:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    clickInside : function(x, y){
        var offset = this.offset();
        var e = new jQuery.Event("click");
        e.pageX = offset.left + x;
        e.pageY = offset.top + y;
        return this.trigger(e); // for chaining
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/maxcal/32z62kyv/

Testing it is then as easy as triggering a click and then checking if the corresponding input has the correct value.
Remember however that the value of a text field is a string. Thats why checking `.toBeGreaterThan` would fail.

```
describe("Edit Locations", function(){

    beforeEach(function(){
        loadFixtures('floor_map_click.html');
        // Jasmine will automatically clean these up for us
        this.nameFields = $(".name-field");
        this.floor_map = $("floor_map_edit");
    });

    // one expectation per example is a good practice. 
    it("updates X coordinate when I click map", function(){
        this.floor_map.clickInside(6, 9);
        // ensure that we are comparing an number and not a string
        expect( parseInt($("#location_x").val()) ).toEqual(6);
    });

    it("updates Y coordinate when I click map", function(){
        this.floor_map.clickInside(6, 9);
        expect( parseInt($("#location_y").val()) ).toEqual(9);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. But, this throws an error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'equal' of undefined. I added a "." before "floor_map_edit". I'm assuming it's not able to find something.

Comment: Sorry, it was a while since I user Jasmine, I accidentally used [Chai](http://chaijs.com/) syntax instead. Jasmine uses snakecase matchers: `toEqual`. Edited.

Comment: *since I used Jasmine

Comment: Yeah I fixed that part. It still gives "Expected NaN to equal 6.". Been trying to fix that but, I haven't had any luck so far. But thanks for your help though.

Comment: You might want to do a sanity check to make sure your fixtures are loaded properly: `expect($("#location_y").length).toBeGreaterThan(0)`

Comment: Yeah, I checked the fixtures. This test passes too.

Comment: Are you sure that the function you are testing works? Add `console.log($("#location_y").val())` to your example. If its `NaN` or `undefined` than you have a legitimate test failure - your test works - the code under test doesn´t.

Comment: I've manually tested the fixture too. It works fine. console.log does not print anything into the server console.

Comment: Log: Started GET "/teaspoon/fixtures/floor_map_click.html?_=1415634694032" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-10 09:51:34 -0600
Processing by Teaspoon::SuiteController#fixtures as HTML
  Parameters: {"_"=>"1415634694032", "filename"=>"floor_map_click"}
  Rendered spec/javascripts/fixtures/floor_map_click.html (3.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 5.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Comment: I´m really sorry it was a typo that I made: `$("floor_map_edit")` should be `$(".floor_map_edit")`

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle with the specs which are passing: http://jsfiddle.net/maxcal/qt2bwqfb/1/. If I knew it was so easy to get jasmine working on jsFiddle I would have done it from the start.

Comment: I fixed the typo long back(first comment). I really appreciate your time. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64643/discussion-between-adroit-and-papirtiger).

Comment: I'll accept the answer because your test works perfectly, just not for me. Anyway thanks!